# How can I pass multiple CSV/JSON files, those contents should be set in POST body data?

Tags: jmeter, http-post, jmeter-5.0

I want to pass multiple CSV/JSON files, those contents should be set as POST body data.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have those files present in some folder the easiest is to:

1. Install [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter) in order to read file names into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
2. Use [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function in order to read the file contents to the request body

Demo:

[image]

Comment: I have 1 Lakh rows in JSON file, If I use __fileToString function, will get a memory issue.

Comment: In this case you can go for [HTTP Raw Request plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-http-raw-request-sampler-when-and-how-to-use-it), it has [nice feature of streaming the file directly to the backend without loading it into memory first](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/fileupload-test-with-JMeter-td4267154.html), check out [HTTP Raw Request for SOAP + MTOM](https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins/c/VDqXDNDCr6w) post for more details.